# In supercollider, what's the role of "*", "#", "_"?

Tags: supercollider

I've been reading through a lot of tutorials and forums on SuperCollider lately, and came accross on some code samples using `*` and `#` and `_`, but I don't find why they are used ? Can someone explain that to me ? Is this related to avoiding multichannel expansion ?

Some samples:

```
(
var list = [1, 2, 3];
func(*list);  // equivalent to func(list[0], list[1], list[2])
)
```

or

```
var a, b, c;
#a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]; // equivalent to a=1; b=2; c=3;
```

or

```
p = Pbind(
    \degree, Pwhite(-7, 12, inf),
    \dur, Pwrand([0.25, Pn(0.125, 2)], #[0.8, 0.2], inf),
    \legato, Pfunc { ~legato }    // retrieves value set by MIDI control
).play;
)
```

or (in the `Pseq`)

```
(
Pbind(
    \mtranspose, -1,
    \octave, 5,
    [\dur, \degree], Ptuple(y.collect(Pseq(_, inf)))
).play
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Asterix

Your sample quickly shows a summary of how this works, but let's expand it a bit and define a three argument function:

```
f = { arg a, b, c;
a + b + c;
};
```

When we want to call the function, we could do: `f.value(1,1,1)`, which returns 3.

Now say for some reason we have an array of three numbers and we want to pass them to the function.

```
a = [1, 1, 1];
```

If we just try `f.value(a)` we just an error.  We could work around this by specifying `f.value(a[0], a[1], a[2])` or we can use the * shortcut. This breaks up the array into a list for passing to a function. So the equivalent, shorter syntax is `f.value(*a)`

## Pound

The pound/hash sign (whichever you call it) can to two different things, depending where it goes.  Let's start with an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
```

Let's say you have three variables and you want them to get the array contents. You could do:

```
b = a[0];
c = a[1];
d = a[2];
```

But that's a lot of typing, so an equivalent shortcut is

```
#b, c, d = a
```

The other meaning of # is when it comes right before the opening bracket of an array. According to Nick Collins:

> A note about efficiency

You will occasionally see

```
 #[1,2,3] //makes a totally fixed (non-dynamic) Array and is slightly cheaper, especially where you're not going to change the Array once you make it
```

rather than

```
 [1,2,3]    //a dynamic array
```

To show the difference

```
 a= #[1,2,3];
 
 
 a[0] //works
 
 
 a[0] = 8 //fails, because it can't be changed
```

(from https://composerprogrammer.com/teaching/supercollider/sctutorial/Technicalities/02%20Arrays.html )

## Underscore

The underscore is doing something called Partial Application. It has a helpfile: https://doc.sccode.org/Reference/Partial-Application.html

What it's doing is replacing an argument declaration and usage.  So in one of their examples, you could write:

```
(1..10).collect({ arg n; n.squared });
```

Or you could shorten it slightly:

```
(1..10).collect( _.squared );
```

So the _ is taking over declaring and using n. Note that the _ also means that you don't use the `{}` brackets.  In your example code, `Ptuple(y.collect(Pseq(_, inf)))` could be rewritten as `Ptuple(y.collect({arg z; Pseq(z, inf)}))`

## Syntax Shortcuts

All of these shortcuts collectively are called "Syntactic Sugar". There's a helpfile called that, but if you're just learning SuperCollider, I suggest you avoid it for now and only dip in hen you come across a symbol doing something strange.

Comment: Thanks. Read that carefully. Really useful. Many examples are using that, so even if I'm not going to use that "synthatic sugar" for now, I needed to understand it to understand the examples.

Comment: The "_" is still not super clear. If I execute ```1.forBy(0.01,-0.01, { arg n; n.postln});``` I've got numbers from 1.0 to 0.01. If I execute ```1.forBy(0.01,-0.01, { _.postln});``` I've got no result... :-/

Comment: Yeah, the _ is not working according to documentation for me either. I think there's some kind of bug or other issue.

Comment: Actually it works, but as many things in SC, this is tricky. "_" suppresses the need/forbids the braces "{ ... }" !!!!. So my example must be rewritten like this : ```1.forBy(0.01,-0.01,  _.postln);``` (note that I remove the ```{ }```).

Comment: Thank you @lvr123 ! I've edited the answer to reflect the information in your comment.